# Is there a Google Sheets formula to count the occurrences of a text value in a sheet but only if the row heading meets a certain condition?

Tags: google-sheets

| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | B | A | A |
| John | C | B | D |
| C | John | A | John |
| D | A | B | A |

For example, I'd like to count occurrences of "John" if Row 1="1". The answer I'm expecting is 3.

I have done something similar with AVERAGEIFS to great effect but not using a text query like this. COUNTIFS gives me an VALUE error that the arrays are different sizes. When I correct that, I have been getting the answer 1. DCOUNTA also got me no closer.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=countif(filter(A:D,A1:D1=1),F2)
```

[image]